# JavaScript prototype inheritance with defineProperty

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, prototype, defineproperty

Say I have this "class":

```
function Car()
{
}
Object.defineProperty(Car.prototype, "Make", 
  {
    get:function() { return this._make; }, 
    set:function(value) { this._make = value; } 
  });
Object.prototype.Drive = function Drive() { console.log("Car.Drive"); }
```

Now I want to make a "child class" using prototype inheritance:

```
function Sedan()
{
}
Sedan.prototype = new Car();
Sedan.prototype.constructor = Sedan;
Sedan.prototype.Drive = function Drive() { Car.prototype.Drive.call(this); console.log("Sedan.Drive"); }
```

Then I can instantiate a car or a sedan, and drive both. Notice how with sedans, Drive also calls base class (Car) Drive:

```
var car = new Car(); car.Drive(); var carMake = car.Make;
var sedan = new Sedan(); sedan.Drive(); var sedanMake = sedan.Make;
```

Is it possible to achieve something similar with properties?

```
Object.defineProperty(Sedan.prototype, "Make", 
  { 
    get: function() { return Car.prototype.Make.<<CALL_GETTER>>(this) + " - Sedan"; },
    set: function(value) { Car.prototype.Make.<<CALL_SETTER>>(this, value.replace(" - Sedan", "")); } 
  });
```

The only idea I could come up with is something like this:

```
Car.prototype.get_Make = function get_Make() { return this._make; }
Car.prototype.set_Make = function set_Make(value) { this._make = value; }
Object.defineProperty(Car.prototype, "Make", 
  {
    get:function() { return this.get_Make(); }, 
    set:function(value) { this.set_Make(value); } 
  });
```

Then the explicit get_Make and set_Make can be overridden similar to Drive. However, this is clunky. Sure, this boilerplate can be extracted into a helper function which defines the get_ and set_ methods and the property in one shot.

```
function DefineVirtualProperty(obj, name, getter, setter)
{
  obj["get_" + name] = getter;
  obj["set_" + name] = setter;
  Object.defineProperty(obj, name, 
    {
      get:function() { return this["get_" + name](); },
      set: function(value) { this["set_" + name](value); }
    });
}

DefineVirtualProperty(Car.prototype, "Make", function() { return this._make; }, function(value) { this._make = value; });
```

However the overriding still looks a big ugly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) to get the property descriptor of the parent property.
Then you can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to invoke it, e.g.:

```js
function Car() {}
Object.defineProperty(Car.prototype, "Make", {
  get() {
    return this._make;
  },
  set(value) {
    this._make = value;
  }
});

function Sedan() {}
Sedan.prototype = Object.create(Car);
Sedan.prototype.constructor = Sedan;

Object.defineProperty(Sedan.prototype, "Make", {
  get() {
    console.log("Sedan Make get");
    let desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Car.prototype, "Make");
    return desc.get.call(this);
  },
  set(value) {
    console.log("Sedan Make set");
    let desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Car.prototype, "Make");
    return desc.set.call(this, value);
  }
});

let sedan = new Sedan();
sedan.Make = 12;
console.log(sedan.Make);
```

A few minor tips:

- Ideally you should use [`Object.create`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create) for prototype creation, since it doesn't call the constructor when creating the object
- Prefer to use [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) instead of directly creating properties on the prototype (so you can set `enumerable` to false)

If you can use ES6 classes this becomes a lot nicer.
You can just use `super` with them to access the parent property:

```js
class Car {
  get Make() {
    return this._make;
  }

  set Make(value) {
    this._make = value;
  }
}

class Sedan extends Car {
  get Make() {
    console.log("Sedan Make get");
    return super.Make;
  }

  set Make(value) {
    console.log("Sedan Make set");
    super.Make = value;
  }
}


let sedan = new Sedan();
sedan.Make = 12;
console.log(sedan.Make);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! The whole `getOwnPropertyDescriptor` rigamarole is still clunky, but at least you don't end up with `get_` and `set_` methods. Unless somebody posts a better answer, I'll mark yours as correct. Can't wait to start using ES6 in production. Thanks for Object.create tip. Regarding JS object properties being enumerated by for..in, I don't really care about that to be honest - I only use the for..in on DTO objects that don't have anything else define anyway.

Comment: @Mr.TA if you can use es6 classes, the last example would be the "clearest" one, since it simply uses `super` to access the parent property